# How to downgrade cakephp3.0 version from latest version using composer?

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I have updated cakephp version 3.1 using composer. How will I downgrade to cakephp3.0 using composer ?

Comment: Are you try to set specific version in composer.json like  ```"cakephp/cakephp": "3.0"``` ?

Comment: @Salines, Accidently we updated the composer, so cakephp version 3.0 changed to 3.2

Comment: can you post you composer.json and composer.lock?